# How do I substitute pink salt for Morton Tender Quick called for in recipe?

Tags: meat, salt, curing

I have a recipe that calls for 1/4 cup Morton Tender Quick for 3 lbs of ribs. I cannot get Tender Quick, but I do have pink salt. I know that I must use much less pink salt, and probably also need to add some regular salt and maybe some sugar, but in what amounts? Previous answers to similar questions do not say. Does anyone out there know?

Comment: You apear to be missing some ingredients in your substitution if you actually need this stuff: "For Home Meat Curing....Morton Tender Quick mix contains salt, the main preserving agent; sugar, both sodium nitrate and sodium nitrite, curing agents that also contribute to development of color and flavor; and propylene glycol to keep the mixture uniform. Morton Tender Quick is NOT a meat tenderizer." https://www.mortonsalt.com/home-product/morton-tender-quick/

Comment: When you say 'pink salt', do you mean Himalayan pink salt (just regular salt with impurities that look pretty) or a curing salt? If it's the former it can't substitute for what you need; if it's the latter I would try to find a specific recipe that uses curing salt.